# Django .initial attribute in the form seems doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a problem with my Django project. I have a Model "Fattura" and a Form "EntrataForm", here is the code of the model:

```
class Fattura(models.Model):
    TIPO_CHOICES = [
        ('T', 'Tasse'),
        ('B', 'Burocrazia'),
        ('C', 'Clienti'),
        ('S', 'Spese'),
    ]

    numero = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    data = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TIPO_CHOICES)
    importo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    viaggi = models.ManyToManyField(Viaggio)

    def clean(self):
        if self.importo is None:
            raise ValidationError('L\'importo non può essere None.')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.numero} - {self.data} - {self.importo} - {self.tipo}"
```

and the form:

```
class EntrataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fattura
        fields = ['numero', 'data', 'cliente','viaggi','importo','tipo']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs.pop('id',None)
        super(EntrataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        importo_finale = 0
        viaggi = Viaggio.objects.filter(cliente_id=id)
        for viaggio in viaggi:
            importo_finale += viaggio.prezzo_viaggio
        print(id)

        self.fields['tipo'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['tipo'].required = False
        self.fields['tipo'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['tipo'].initial = 'C'
        self.fields['viaggi'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['viaggi'].required = False
        self.fields['viaggi'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['viaggi'].initial = viaggi
        self.fields['cliente'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['cliente'].required = False
        self.fields['cliente'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['cliente'].initial = Cliente.objects.get(id=id)
        self.fields['importo'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['importo'].required = False
        self.fields['importo'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['importo'].initial = importo_finale
        print(self.fields['importo'].initial)
```

As you can see i use the ".initial" attribute for 4 fields, but only "importo" doesn't initialize correctly. In **init** the final value is correct and the last line print what i want, but when it return to the view and it execute the line form.is_valid() it raises the ValidationError, because "importo" is None. Other fields don't have this error, but the procedure is the same, i can't understand where the value "importo" become None.

Here is the view code:

```
def entrata(request, id):
    viaggi = Viaggio.objects.filter(cliente_id=id)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntrataForm(request.POST, id=id)
        if form.is_valid():
            nuova_fattura = form.save()

            return redirect('fatture')
        else:
            # Se il form non è valido, potresti restituire un template renderizzato
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('fatture')

    else:

        form = EntrataForm(id=id)


        return render(request, 'fatture/crea/cliente/entrata.html', {'form': form, 'cliente': cliente, 'viaggi':viaggi})
```

Here is the template:

```
{% extends 'fatture/index.html' %}

{% block corpo %}
<body>
    <button onclick="location.href = '{% url 'fatture' %}'" id="indietro">Indietro</button>
    <section>
        <h2>Viaggi per {{ cliente }}</h2>
        <h3>Seleziona i viaggi che vuoi inserire nella fattura</h3>
        <div id="banner">
            <form id="fattura-form" method="post" action="{% url 'entrata' cliente.id%}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="{{ form.numero.id_for_label }}">Numero:</label>
    {{ form.numero }}
    <br>

    <label for="{{ form.data.id_for_label }}">Data:</label>
    {{ form.data }}
    <br>



    <button type="submit">Inserisci</button>
</form>

            <table id="tabella-fatture" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Distanza</th>
            <th>Prezzo Viaggio</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for viaggio in viaggi %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ viaggio.data_viaggio }}</td>
                <td>{{ viaggio.distanza_km }}</td>
                <td>{{ viaggio.prezzo_viaggio }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
    </section>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my template, i put {{form.as_p}} instead of the two form value and now the problem is also on other fields. Now the form.error is:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>viaggi<ul class="errorlist"><li>&quot;&quot; non � un valore valido.</li></ul></li><li>importo<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo � obbligatorio.</li></ul></li><li>tipo<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo � obbligatorio.</li></ul></li><li>__all__<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>L&#x27;importo non pu� essere None.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: You'd need to show us the template or the code that makes that POST request. `initial` is only used for rendering the initial value in the form, if you're getting an error for a field being `None` and this code doesn't remove it somewhere its going missing between you rendering the form and the user submitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not rendering the field in the template, so the field and its initial value is not included when the form is POSTed. The request's POST data in the view does not contain the `importo` field, and the form is instantiated with that incomplete data. And the initial value set by you in the init method can't subsitute a value that is missing from data:

> Use initial to declare the initial value of form fields at runtime.  ... These values are only displayed for unbound forms, and they’re not used as fallback values if a particular value isn’t provided.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values

Since the model requires a value for `importo` (`null!=True`), form validation would *normally* fail here with a message that `importo` is required. But you set `importo` to not required in the form init method, meaning form validation passes, at first at least. Then your custom clean method on the model triggers a validation error since the value for `importo` was never set, i.e. it is still `None`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is there a way to initialize the values in the correct way? Now i fixed it deleting the line with "forms.HiddenInput()" and it works.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "initialize the values in a correct way"? Do you want to set default values for the fields?

Comment: Yes... exactly!

Comment: You can do it the way you did - but you need to remember to render the HiddenInputs on the page, so that their values are included in the request data. Downside is, that a user could manipulate those inputs on the page to override your defaults. Alternatively, you can add your defaults to the form data in the view when instantiating it. For example `data = request.POST.copy(); data.setdefault("importo", <your_default_value>)` would set `importo` if the request data does not already contain it.